# Social Golfer Problem with exactly two occurrences of each pairing

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-designs

The Social Golfer problem goes roughly as follows:

"If I have *g* groups of *p* people each, how do I arrange them over *n* sessions such that all people meet each other exactly once?"

For example, where *g* = *p* = 4, and *n* = 5, how do you arrange 16 people in 4 groups of 4, playing 5 rounds of golf, such that they each golf with everyone else 1 time?

This is answered elsewhere, but I can't find anything on a wider case - where the number of meeting points is not 1.

Specifically, I'd like to arrange 16 people in 4 groups of 4, over 10(?) rounds, such that everyone plays with everyone else exactly twice, but no group of 4 is repeated. Ideally no given combination of 3 should be repeated either. So if A/B/C/D play a game, then A/B should meet again exactly one more time in a future game, but neither C nor D should be involved.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I can at least give you the name for it; this is called a _resolvable (balanced incomplete) block design_ or RBIBD, with parameters $(v, k, \lambda)=(pg, p, 2)$. $v=pg$ is the number of people, $k=p$ is the number of people per block (golf group), $\lambda=2$ is the number of times each pair of people appear together.